# How to filter dates based on its time in Loopback 4?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I want to find out all the dates which have time more than 10.30 am.

```
let whereBuilder = new WhereBuilder();
whereBuilder.gt('sessionStartedOn', '10:30:00');
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. Are there any wildcard characters I should be adding?

The query in PostgreSQL would be something like this -

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_part('hour', sessionStartedOn) >= 10 AND date_part('minutes', sessionStartedOn) > 30;

Answer (score 0):

I think the second parameter should be of the same type as the value contained by the variable named by the first parameter. In your case I presume it is date. For example: "2022-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.filter.wherebuilder.lte.html

PS. If you want to filter for values greater than the value passed as a parameter you should use .gt (>) or .gte (>=) methods.

Comment: Oops. I made a mistake while typing the code example here. It should be gt. Thanks for letting me know :)
But still how to pick dates from the table which has time greater than 10.30 AM? If we go direct PostgreSQL way, DATE_PART() can be used but how to do same thing in the Loopback way?
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_part('hour', sessionStartedOn) = 10 AND date_part('minutes', sessionStartedOn) > 30;

Comment: If you can modify the table/view you can add a separate column for time and filter by that column or you could try to use WhereBuilder.like() method and pass as the second parameter a regex.

Comment: Yes. Did something like this.